# factory pattern with lambda

Tags: python, factory

How would you create a factory based method using lambda?

function signature looks like this. Factory gets a string parameter and returns the instance.

```
class Foo:

    @abstractmethod
    def store(factory: Callable[[str], Bar])
       obj = factory("abc") # store or call to get instance


class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

How to call this method using lambda?

```
Foo.store(lambda k: Bar(k))
```

Error

> Parameter 'factory' unfilled

Comment: What is `foo`? It seems it is `foo = Foo`, when it should be `foo = Foo()`

Comment: yes, edited. `foo = Foo()`

Comment: The code worked fine when I tried it, but I had to fill in a lot of details and fix the syntax. What's giving you that error? Please make a [mre].

Comment: Assuming `Bar` is somewhat of `Bar = type("Bar", (), dict(__init__=lambda self, k: None))` your code is correct and works

Comment: yes I have the syntax error issue, can you please post your solution.

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but in your real code, does `store` need `self`? If not, it should probably be a static method or just a plain function.

Comment: static, or plain function, doesn't matter, I have the syntax error which I mentioned above. but I changed it to static

Comment: That's not a syntax error, it's a PyCharm warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `store()` is called on the class, not an instance, it needs to be declared as a static method.

```
class Foo:

    @staticmethod
    def store(factory: Callable[[str], Bar]):
        obj = factory("abc")  # store or call to get instance
```

Otherwise, it's expected to be called on an instance, and the first argument should be `self`, which receives the instance.

Also, `obj` is just a local variable. If you want this to persist, you need to use `Foo.obj`.